# C++ Object Orientated Rhombus

Tags: c++, oop, object, shapes, centroid

I'm having issues with an assignment I've been given, the problem is that I cannot find any resources in anyway similar to the code I've been given. I've read through so many documents trying to find similarities but cannot find anything useful.

I need help trying to understand this code and how to use it to create a Rhombus. **The only things I can't grasp is how to create a Rhombus shape that belongs to the Shape class. Apply a centroid to that Rhombus and then add vertices using a push_back method.** Unfortunately this push back method needs to be used, I failed the exam by just using drawLine(10,10,40,10); etc for drawing lines where I wanted.

I'll be grinding this for a solid week so I should respond quickly.

```
//This is the rhombus.cpp file
#include "rhombus.h"

Rhombus::Rhombus(Vertex point, int radius) : Shape(point)
{
    if((radius>centroid.getX()/2) || (radius>centroid.getY()/2)) // Inteded to be a y?
    {
        cout << "Object must fit on screen." << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }

    Rhombus shape1(20, 20);
    shape1.plotVertices();

}

void Rhombus::plotVertices()
{
    //vertices.push_back(Vertex(centroid.getX(), centroid.getY() + radius));
    //vertices.push_back(Vertex(centroid.getX(), centroid.getY()));
    //vertices.push_back(Vertex(centroid.getX(), centroid.getY()));
    //vertices.push_back(Vertex(centroid.getX(), centroid.getY()));
}
```

---

```
// This is the rhombus.h file
#include "shape.h"

class Rhombus : public Shape 
{
    int radius;
    void plotVertices();
    Rhombus(Vertex point, int radius = 10);
    int area();
    int perimeter();
};
```

---

```
// This is the shape.cpp file
#include "shape.h"

Shape::Shape(Vertex point) : centroid(point)
{
    // constructs a shape

}

void Shape::drawShape()
{

    list<Vertex>::iterator current = vertices.begin();
    list<Vertex>::iterator previous = vertices.begin();
    while(current!=vertices.end())
    {
        Console::gotoXY((*current).getX(),(*current).getY());
        cout << "*";
        if(current!=vertices.begin())
            drawLine((*current).getX(),(*current).getY(), (*previous).getX(),            (*previous).getY());
        previous = current;
        current++;
    }
    previous = vertices.begin();

    //Debug assertion error here.
    drawLine(vertices.back().getX(), vertices.back().getY(), vertices.front().getX(),     vertices.front().getY());
}

void Shape::drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{      

    bool steep = (abs(y2 - y1) > abs(x2 - x1));
    if(steep)
    {
        swap(x1, y1);
        swap(x2, y2);
    }

    if(x1 > x2)
    {
        swap(x1, x2);
        swap(y1, y2);
    }

    int dx = x2 - x1;
    int dy = abs(y2 - y1);

    float error = dx / 2.0f;
    int ystep = (y1 < y2) ? 1 : -1;
    int y = y1;
    int maxX = x2;

    for(int x=x1; x<maxX; x++)
    {
        if(steep)
        {
            Console::gotoXY(y,x);
            cout << "*";
        }
        else
        {
            Console::gotoXY(x,y);
        cout << "*";
        }
        error -= dy;
        if(error < 0)
        {
            y += ystep;
            error += dx;
        }
    }
}


double Shape::round(double x)
{
    if (ceil(x+0.5) == floor(x+0.5))
    {
        int a = (int) ceil(x);
        if (a%2 == 0)
            return ceil(x);
        else
            return floor(x);
    }
    else 
        return floor(x+0.5);
}

void Shape::outputStatistics()
{

}
```

---

```
// This is the shape.h file
#pragma once
#include "console.h"
#include "vertex.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846

class Shape
{
    list<Vertex>::iterator itr;
protected:
    list<Vertex> vertices;
    Vertex centroid;
    void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);

    Shape(Vertex point);
    double round(double x);

public:
    void drawShape();
    virtual int area() = 0;
    virtual int perimeter() = 0;
    virtual void outputStatistics();
    void rotate(double degrees);
    void scale(double factor);
};
```

Comment: Please take this question to your instructor or TA.  Stack Overflows format makes it very difficult for us to help you in a way that ensures you will actually learn something.

Comment: Rhombus defined by a single radius value? What kind of geometry is that?

Comment: I asked my tutor what did I do wrong and what can I improve on from the last time I failed. his response was 'Read the marking scheme' so help is out of the question there.

Comment: Programming-wise, there is a rather big set of problems with this code (and your understanding of basic concepts) you need to address. I suggest you build your program by starting from an empty main function, adding **one** class or method at a time, and compiling everything again and making sure you are not breaking it. If you are stuck at any step, ask a question about that specific problem.

Comment: The code works, I don't get any errors. Problem is that this is the code given. It needs to be used and needs to be added onto. I wish I could start a completely new program because at the knowledge I have now, throwing this in my face is just confusing.

Comment: Same thing. You start with what was given to you and add/change one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, `Rhombus` is already a subclass of `Shape` (`class Rhombus : public Shape`) so you just have to create an instance of `Rhombus` for all the magic to happen.

`Shape` is defined such that the `Vertex` passed to it (as the `point` parameter) is used to initialize the `centroid` instance variable automatically; so you can use `centroid` as the centroid for any operation requiring centroid-related data, either from within `Shape` or from within one of its subclasses like `Rhombus`.

Similarly, the list `vertices` is available for `Shape` and all its subclasses as an instance variable. If you look at the rest of the code (e.g. `Shape::drawShape`), you will notice how `vertices` has been used for manipulating the vertices of the current shape.

What you have to do here is quite similar to that. For example,

```
Rhombus::Rhombus(Vertex point, int radius) : Shape(point)
{
    if((radius>centroid.getX()/2) || (radius>centroid.getY()/2)) // Inteded to be a y?
    {
        cout << "Object must fit on screen." << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }

    // create vertices for a rhombus with horizontal and vertical diagonals
    vertices.push_back(Vertex(point.getX() - radius, point.getY()));
    vertices.push_back(Vertex(point.getX(), point.getY() - radius));
    vertices.push_back(Vertex(point.getX() + radius, point.getY()));
    vertices.push_back(Vertex(point.getX(), point.getY() + radius));
}
```

When you are inside `Rhombus::Rhombus` (the constructor), you are already **inside** a rhombus that has just been created; you don't have to create a `Rhombus` object again. You just have to "decorate" the instance by adding vertices, and defining a centroid (which has been already done).

Just imagine that you are creating a `Rhombus` out of a `Shape`; you need to create 4 vertices and add them to the structure that keeps track of the list of all vertices.

Comment: What would happen if the instance of the Rhombus had been set out like this
`Rhombus::Rhombus(Vertex centroid, int radius) : Shape(centroid)`
would it still be the same or would I need to do something to centroid? @Janaka Bandara

Comment: @HLG `centroid` is just the variable name used for the constructor parameter here; doesn't make a difference whether it reads as `centroid` or `point` (the `Vertex` parameter coming into the `Rhombus` constructor as a **local variable** is directly passed to the `Shape` constructor, which would then be assigned to the `centroid` **instance variable** of `Shape`). (However, you would obviously have to use `centroid` instead of `point` in the `vertices.push_back(...)` method calls inside `Rhombus::Rhombus`.)

Comment: In addition, `centroid` in `if((radius>centroid.getX()/2) || ...` will refer to the **local variable** `centroid` within the scope of `Rhombus::Rhombus`; however, even that won't make a difference in this case, since the instance variable `centroid` has already been initialized with the same value as the local variable. If you want to refer explicitly to the instance variable from within `Rhombus::Rhombus`, you may use `this->centroid` instead.